# JavaFx - Switch between "InnerScenes" into a RootScene

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, window

I was wondering if in JavaFx it was possible to create a **RootScene** for the **Stage** and then change (for example) in a **Pane** (with its own **fx:id**) different "*InnerScenes*", so as to allow me to have a **RootController** for all those components that remain the same between the switches and specific *components* and *controller* for the **InnerScenes**.

---

PS: I created an image to try to explain a little better what I mean.

[image]

Comment: See if this is close to what you are looking for https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX.

Comment: I think you do not want to change scenes but rather change a child pane inside a parent pane. It is possible. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929321/3992939). What should trigger the change of inner child pane ? What did you try ?

Comment: I tried with a SubScene component, and it seemed to work, but when I try to use the "subScene.setRoot()" method to change from one scene to another, the SubScene remains empty.
Without giving any error.